# Rename multiple files in a directory in objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, nsfilemanager, file-rename

I need to remove the first 4 characters of the names of over 100 files in a certain directory, can I do this with an obj-c program or a c ++  program and if so how?

Comment: Does it have to be an Objective-C program? You can accomplish this with a shell script fairly easily: `for file in \`ls\`; do mv $file ${file:4}; done`

Comment: @LewisElliott: `ls` is a shell command that will list all the files in the current directory. So you'll need to be in the directory whose contents you want to change when you run that shell script.

Comment: wow thats nice, can you add a string to say 4 characters in from the end using this method? so say image.png I can rename to image@2x.png ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

The `NSFileManager` class provides all the methods you need.

To get the contents of the directory use the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` method.
To rename the file you need to use the `moveItemAtPath` method.

Take a look at the class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Steps:
1. Get the names of the files in the dir.
2. Iterate all the files and use the moveItemAtPath to rename.